# Use mysql_query instead of $wpdb query

Tags: query, wpdb

I have a custom table inside my wordpress database called test.

What if i query this table using mysql_query() instead of using for example $wpdb->get_results()

Will this affect my performance?

Ty very much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and short:

- mysql_query() = **Faster!**
- $wpdb->get_results() = **Safer!**

But in most cases since `$wpdb` is a global object and already in the memory using it will be be as fast as `mysql_query()`.

> Will this affect my performance?

It can affect for better performance changes but they would be minor changes that its just not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins caching DB queries hook into the WordPress API. If you don’t use the API your queries aren’t cached. The result is a slower site.